# How are the painting of invisible controls handled in WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, embedded, compact-framework

I'm trying to override the **OnPaint** events of the windows form in **.NET Compact Framework**.

So far, I'm able to draw the controls with gradients, rounded rectangles etc that would not normally be possible with regular controls.

However, I'm having problems when I want to make a control invisible. Right now, what I do is re-draw all the controls except those invisible ones. Since it takes a bit of time, it causes some flicker.

Does anyone know how windows handles painting the "invisible" controls? Or can you suggest any algorithm or method on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be several things you're doing.

1. Don't paint right to the Graphics object handed to you in `OnPaint`.  Draw to a back buffer, and paint that to the Graphics at the end.
2. Override `OnPaintBackground` and have it do nothing.
3. Invalidate only areas that change, not the entire screen, whenever possible to keep the clipping region small

If you're changing a single control to "not visible", then you'd change it and invalidate just it's bounding rect.  The in `OnPaint` you'd do your drawing, omitting the "invisible" control based on the Visibility property.  Only the clipping region will get updated.  You could even go one further by checking the incoming clipping region on `OnPaint` and only bothering to do draw logic draw that region.  That's a bit more complex though, and often isn't required.

Comment: Would he have to invalidate any controls that are behind the "invisible" one, or container it sits in, to get them to repaint so there is no hole?

Comment: When you invalidate the region, OnPaint gets called and tells you the clipping area.  You're going to paint into that area (or paint the whole Form, and the OS ignores everything but that region anyway).  So you have to paint *something* there, yes (or have the base OnPaintBackground deal with it).

Comment: thanks for the answer. so far it works OK. the flickering goes away when overridding the OnPaintBackground event and have it do nothing.

but now I've got a new problem, how do you actually remove the "corners" in the rounded rectangle ?

previously, it looked to work because the background color is white. but when i changed the background color of form itself, the corners are visible.

Comment: Take a look at SetColorKey and color key transparency

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, would it be possible to call any overload of the [Invalidate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method on the appropriate controls to reduce total number of controls that need to be repainted?