# Control.Invalidate does not trigger the paint event of hidden or invisible Control

Tags: c#, winforms, paint, invalidation

When I call Invalidate method on a hidden or invisible control, paint event is not triggered.

Is this the behavior of windows forms controls ? Is there any documentation available ?

I checked the documentation of `Control.Invalidate` method but it does not mention about invisible controls
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.windows.forms.control.invalidated(v=vs.110).aspx

I checked the following SO question [How are the painting of invisible controls handled in WinForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584912) but it is asked for flickering problem in compact framework and not related to my question

Comment: Why are you relying on an invisible control being painted?

Comment: My control is present in tab page. I want to ensure it is not updating or painting if it is not visible. Because painting invisible control decreases performance

Comment: Calling invalidate only puts control into a paint-ready state. Paint is not triggered until it is really drawn onto screen. Therefore, don't worry - such performance is well handled by Windows.

Comment: @Tommy, thanks but MSDN says "Invalidates the entire surface of the control and causes the control to be redrawn."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well i think the best way to investigate this was to check the source code from Microsoft. This is what's going on:

When the `Control` is set to `Visible` false, the Control's handle created flag is also set to `false`.

The `Invalidate()` method (source code below) doesn't do its work when `IsHandleCreated` is false; That's the entire story actually.

```
/// <include file='doc\Control.uex' path='docs/doc[@for="Control.Invalidate3"]/*' />
/// <devdoc>
///     Invalidates the control and causes a paint message to be sent to the control.
///     This will not force a synchronous paint to occur, calling update after
///     invalidate will force a synchronous paint.
/// </devdoc>
public void Invalidate(bool invalidateChildren)
{
    if (IsHandleCreated)
    {
        if (invalidateChildren)
        {
            SafeNativeMethods.RedrawWindow(new HandleRef(window, Handle),
                                            null, NativeMethods.NullHandleRef,
                                            NativeMethods.RDW_INVALIDATE |
                                            NativeMethods.RDW_ERASE |
                                            NativeMethods.RDW_ALLCHILDREN);
        }
        else
        {
            // It's safe to invoke InvalidateRect from a separate thread.
            using (new MultithreadSafeCallScope())
            {
                SafeNativeMethods.InvalidateRect(new HandleRef(window, Handle),
                                                    null,
                                                    (controlStyle & ControlStyles.Opaque) != ControlStyles.Opaque);
            }
        }

        NotifyInvalidate(this.ClientRectangle);
    }
}
```